# Rails: problems performing 'split' on string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When creating a new entry for my "question" object, my code works fine.

However, using various methods, I can't get the edit route to submit to `def update` correctly.

After a lot of head-scratching, I realized my create method performs a split on a named object like this:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  ...
  @question.options = @question.options.split(',').collect(&:strip)
```

In my update method,

```
def update
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

I need to somehow format the `options` of `params[:question]` in this line:

```
  if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
```

Otherwise, `update_attributes` fails. I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help appreciated.

Output of `@question.options` after formatting with split:

```
["options", "---\n- Extremely unlikely\n- Unlikely\n- Neutral\n- Likely\n- Extremely likely\n-"]
```

Comment: please tell us the output of `@question.options`.

Comment: can you please show your the form you are using to update @question.

Comment: What are the options doing in params[:question]? How does the update_attributes fail? Does the update action fire? Throw an error? Not update an attribute? If so, which attribute?

Comment: The options are in params[:question] because they are being passed in to #update from #edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should move your formatting code to a callback in your Question class:

```
class Question
  before_save :format_options
  def format_options
    write_attribute :options, read_attribute(:options).split(',').collect(&:strip)
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked so damn well. I've been spending HOURS on this. What an elegant solution. THANK YOU.